# Ошибка при подключении шаблона Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Подключил шаблон. Перехожу на страницу сайта, там где должен подключаться index.php отображается ошибка Cannot find 'news' template with page:

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Title");
?>
<section>Содержимое станицы</section>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с шаблоном компонента, полагаю его физически не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Удаление компонента новости в режиме правки решает проблему.